# How to check for one of multiple accepted options in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to validate the value of an input variable, and prompt the user for valid value, until I get a valid input ('1' or '2'). I've tried:

```
while option not in 1 2
do :
    read -p "Please choose an option" option
done
```

How this can be done in bash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The classical way is:

`while ! { test "$option" = 1 || test "$option" = 2; }; do ...`

but a cleaner way is to use a case statement:

```
while :; do
  case "$option" in 
    1|2) break ;;
    *) ... ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Thanks! It did the job but was hoping to find something with the logic "does not belong to array".

Comment: @Odin `bash` doesn't really have a container type like that. Arrays are really an extra form of quoting, to make things likes `args=("foo bar" "1 2"); somecommand "${args[@]}"` possible (i.e., calling `somecommand` with 2 arguments that contain whitespace, rather than 4 arguments).

Comment: @chepner yes true. I read few posts about this an aparently not doable. with this logic.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `select` builtin:

```
$ cat select.sh
#!/bin/bash

options=("Option 1" "Option 2")

echo "Please choose an option:"
select option in "${options[@]}"; do
        [ -n "${option}" ] && break
done
echo "You picked: ${option}"
```

```
$ ./select.sh
Please choose an option:
1) Option 1
2) Option 2
#? 3
#? xyz
#? 2
You picked: Option 2
```

Comment: +1 for the right tool. ;)

Comment: You can also provide a more descriptive prompt inside the loop provided by `select` by setting the value of `PS3`.

Comment: @chepner: does bash support a way to temporarily set PS3 for select? With `perl` I would write `local PS3="Your input > "` but does `bash` have anything similar? With real commands I could write `PS3="Your input > " select ...` but it turns out that `select` is a shell keyword and you cannot specify environment for a keyword.

Comment: Nothing except `select` uses `P3`, so I don't seen any need for temporary changes. Just set it to whatever value you want the next `select` to use.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash`, you can use pattern matching to test `$option`:

```
while [[ $option != [12] ]]; do
    read -p "Please choose an option: " option
done
```

Comment: Ok that's exactly what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do
    echo "Please choose an option"
    read val
    [[ $val != 1 && $val != 2 ]] || break
done
```

Comment: Thanks this also work but I can't upvote anyone.

Comment: @odin now you can...

Answer (score 1):

Or if you plan to evaluate more options, use case:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  read -p "Please choose an option" option

  case "$option" in
    [12]) break
          ;;
    *)    echo "whatever"
  esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `while` condition using `{...}` list construct and `shell globbing`:

```
option=0

while [[ $(echo {1,2}) != *"$option"* ]]; do
    read -p "Please choose an option: " option
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the most common way

```
while [[ "$option" -ne 1 ]]  || [[ "$option" -ne 2 ]]; do
          read -p "Please choose an option" option
done
```

Comment: I was looking for something easier to expand and debug. For example using case/esac.